# What type of construction is "In came I. I. Chundrigar..." where a preposition "in" is placed before the verb "came"?

Tags: grammar, syntax, inversion

In the red-marked line i.e.

> In came I.I. Chundrigar, a Bombay barrister, to join the Mad Hatter's dance.

See preposition "In" is placed before verb "came".
What types of syntax is it and what is the meaning of it?

[image: writing by Anthony Mascarenhas]

Answer (score 0):

In that sentence the verb appears before the subject (came I) and a preposition starts the sentence.

This inversion is a rhetorical strategy  often used in oral narratives.  It can  emphasize the physical dimension of the narrated action and/or delay the appearance of the subject.  There is a kind of delight taken in the delayed or slo-mo unfolding of events.

> The door opens and **in walks the strangest** ...

Comment: No! it is not `came I` rather `came I.I. Chundrigar` where `I.I. Chundrigar` is a name. Elaboration of this name is `Ismail Ibrahim Chundrigar`.

Comment: @SIslam This *information-packaging construction* is termed **subject–dependent inversion** in *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Huddleston & Pullum, 2002, pp.1385–90).

Comment: @ SIslam: That makes no difference.  *In came {subject}*

Comment: **Inversion Written and Spoken Contemporary English** a good book to go with!! thanks every one. My problem was the placement of preposition **in**.  Why **in** does not come after the subject? Why not **Came I.I. Chundrigar in, a Bombay barrister, to join the Mad Hatter's dance?**

Comment: _In_ is not a preposition here, but either an adverb or a part of the phrasal verb _come in_,